# File to std::string_view

Tags: c++, stl, string-view

Is it possible to load file directly into the std::string_view?

Directly = without creating the proxy std::string from stringstream.

It would make a lot of my code faster.

Comment: Probably not as much faster as you would like. Reading from a file is sssssloooowwww, and if you gotta do it, ya gotta do it. Not sure what you need the `stringstream` for. Add the code for that, or ask another question about it, and there's good odds someone can give you a hand trimming it out.

Comment: Show your code which you want speed up then you will receive a feedback how this can be properly achieved.

Comment: I cannot, because it does not exist yet. I heard that _substr_ method works faster, and i wanted to use it in CSV file read only.

Comment: You probably can map the file on memory using `mmap` (linux) or `virutal mapping `(win32) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, no.

`std::string_view` refers to a region of memory, but *it does not own that memory.* This means that an `std::string_view` *requires* that another object exist which actually holds the `char` objects that it refers to.

If an `std::string_view` is referring to an `std::string` and that string's lifetime ends, then the `std::string_view` is now effectively a dangling reference/pointer and trying to read characters from it would cause undefined behavior.

Note that `std::string_view` can refer to contiguous sequences of `char` objects aside from `std::string`, such as a simple `char` array or an `std::vector<char>`, but regardless of what it refers to, the referent *must exist at least as long as the `std::string_view` will be used.*

Comment: Thanks! I thought about string as a byte array for that represents the file.

Comment: @JWZ1996 Note that if you `mmap()` the file, you can construct a `std::string_view` directly against the memory-mapped region, as indicated in the other answer. (Boost is not required, but gives proper RAII to the mmap resource.)

Comment: @cdhowie i did not :), i removed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to `boost`, you can point a string view to the `data()` of a [`boost::iostreams::mapped_file`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file).

Comment: @Raxvan those are platform dependant